# Automate TV Capture Linux

Tags: linux, video-capture, vlc

I have a cheap Happauge WinTV Go 878 card running on an AMD 2.4Ghz single core PC from about 7 years ago. I'm trying to config some ghetto security system and I need some help. I have these cheap wireless cameras I bought from Lowes that I've installed and they only have RCA composite out. On my PC I have WinXP and Linux partitions. The idea is to enable remote surveillance. I can get the video input card to run video full screen under WinXP using Nero 6 and configuring it to use composite input. The problem is when I switch to Linux. I need help on the quickest dirtiest solution for getting a streaming solution in place. I have probably -13 more days to finalize and I'm ready to panic. I'm running Mepis 6 on one partition and WinXP on the other. I've packed away my original WinXP disc so its not accessible. I have been very careful not to overwrite my WinXP partition because its the only thing that I can rely on so far but I really want to run this on a fresh Linux install for reliability reasons. (My WinXP partition has been very flaky.) any help would be immensiy appreciated and I'm willing to donate all my S/O rep to get to an appropriate solution.

Comment: check gstreamer. Also, this is not the site for this type of question, maybe superuser

Answer (score 0):

[ZoneMinder](http://www.zoneminder.com/)

Answer (score 0):

For a down and dirty do it yourself job for a single camera.

On Ubuntu:

1) Plug the camera into the composite line on the tuner card using the supplied dongle.

2) Download and install TVTime.  The picture in my opinion is better than VLC.  Its easy.

Right click in the tvtime window and through the menus set it to composite.

You are gonna need some other hardware to demultiplex composite lines but the steps above will do one.  You might be able to find a device that takes a number of composite inputs and turns them into analog tv frequencies.

Good luck!